# Returning different DNS records depending on who asks

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

In `BIND 9` (`named`), is there any way to return different `A` records depending on the asker's `IP` address?

When receiving a query for a certain `DNS` name, I'd like to return external `IP` address for the queries received from the outside world, and internal `IP` address for the queries received from the internal subnet.

**Update**:

Views seem to work OK, but there are about `300` records in the zone file.

Should I copy the whole file (and manage two files from now on) if I only want a single `DNS` record to be returned differently?

Comment: Why copy? A site with 300 records certainly did not enter them by hand. They are probably generated automatically from the provisioning database, no? So, Generating them twice is not a big deal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BIND 9 has a feature to do exactly that, called "views".

There is a good article about how to use them on O'Reilly.

http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/oreilly/networking/news/views_0501.html

Comment: There are about 300 records in the zone file. Should I copy the whole file (and manage two files) if I only want a single DNS record to be returned differenty?

Comment: I would suggest creating a new zone within your view for that single record. The zone will be the full address of the record you wish to override and will contain only an SOA and an @ record.

This should prevent any unnecessary duplication whilst keeping BIND authoritative, as usual, for the rest of the domain.

Comment: No need to copy, BIND can include a zone file and therefore saves you typing (or programming).

Answer (score 2):

For your future reference and for searching purposes this is known as "split horizon dns" It is supported in many DNS packages, including Djbdns.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [you can use views](http://www.bind9.net/manual/bind/9.3.2/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#view_statement_grammar), which are basically a wrapper around your config that limit the configuration to only a certain segment of client IPs.